# Why was this question plus answer closed?

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, specific-question

[IE10 unexpectedly sends a HEAD request for PDF. What has changed?](https://superuser.com/questions/560647/ie10-unexpectely-sends-a-head-request-before-handing-pdf-over-to-pdf-viewer#comment683132_560647)

I had a genuine problem. I am not the only one. While I researched the question, which was not obvious, I came upon the solution. I post the solution for whoever else has this issue.

My question gets closed as not a real question. What about this is not a real question?

I used the word **unexpectedly**: adjective
*not expected; unforeseen; surprising: an unexpected development.*, assuming that people would get that the question is why that suddenly has changed and not just close it because it missed an actual question mark

I can change the title to be more generic but that is about all I can see I could improve.

**UPDATE**: changed title from *IE10 unexpectedly sends a HEAD request before handing PDF over to PDF viewer*

Comment: Your post really doesn't include any (literal) question. Consider editing it to add one, even if you knew the answer.

Comment: I find it very strange that due to a missing question mark, an actual issue with solution is just closed. I have been active on SE sites for a long time and this never cease to surprise the hell out of me.

Comment: It's easy to see the problem you're facing if you already knew the answer for it. Just imagine reading your post without the answer—it's certainly lacking a clear description of what the problem is and what you want to do about it.

Comment: Hmm, hence the upvote for the answer. And the comment AND the answer I gave even explained that our server did not like the sudden HEAD. People with the problem will get the issue at hand

Comment: Please, in the future, focus on the actual question without considering the answers or any comments that might go unnoticed. Self-answered questions should be held up to the same standards as others. Thanks for improving your post.

Comment: You are welcome. thanks for re-opening it

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your question is that you mention the problem but you don't mention what do you want to do with it - are you looking at steps to correct what IE sends? Are you looking at ways of getting around the problem?

Please note that what's obvious to you after your hours of research isn't necessarily general perception.

Your question says

> IE10 sends HEAD request.

Ok. So what? What do want people who answer the question(let's ignore for now that you've answered it) do? Do want to change IE's behaviour? Do you want to change server behaviour? Editing the question and mentioning the intent should go long way in clearing why it isn't a real question

Comment: UNEXPECTEDLY is the working word here. I will change it, but am genuinely surprised that an issue is closed just because there is a missing question mark

Comment: @mplungjan - In the English language sentences that end in a question mark are considered a question.  If you don't include a question mark how is one suppose to determine what part of your statement is the question?  Lets forget for a minute that person might not actually have the problem themselfs.  Its well documented that a question on this website should not actually contained the question itself.  Your original revision of the question didn't contain a question from my perspective it was a statement.

Comment: I will put 10 question marks next time...

Comment: It's not about a question _mark_. It's about a question. There was _no question._ Simply providing an error message is rather useless. (And FWIW, "What changed?" isn't very helpful either.) What if you wanted to fix this on the client side (IE10) rather than the server side? Upon initially reading the question I would have assumed that one would attempt to fix this client side, as most of us on SU aren't sysadmins.

Comment: @mplungjan - You wanted to know the reason it was closed.  The reason I explained is the reason I flagged it for a moderator to review it.  Tanner is right its not actually about the question mark, its the fact, clearly the question was saved because you made the required edits to make it a constructive question.